# Rails environment groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment

We have two deployed environments, staging and production. Is there some way from Rails.env to be able to call something like `Rails.env.deployed?` instead of `Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?` or is there some way to add this method myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add the method yourself:

```rb
def (Rails.env).deployed?
  Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
end
```

The parenthesis are required to tell the interpreter that the method should be defined on the object returned by the `Rails.env` call

Comment: I see, where would I place this definition?

Comment: config/environment.rb for example?